# Change Version Option Grayed out in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-pro, versioning

I am experimenting with versioning data from an SDE database in ArcGIS Pro. I able able to create a new version, no problems, but when I go to change the version in the Data Source tab on the Contents Pane by right clicking on the SDE source it is all grayed out, not allowing me to click anything. See figure. I can only work and make edits using the Default version, not my new personal version.

[image]

Note, I can work on this ArcGIS Pro created version of the SDE in ArcMap without any issues. Only happening in Pro. I have, somewhat, done this before and did not have the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible Pro has opened an edit session automatically? That would disable changing versions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same user, instance and database that you're using in ArcMap? If so, I would verify the settings used to create the versions. Review the versions that you are able to view or manage in ArcMap vs ArcGIS Pro. Version access/privileges depend on the user type and specifc permission level (Public, Protected, Public) given to the version. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/geodatabases/overview/create-modify-and-delete-versions.htm